# PhpMyAdmin page shows blank page on browser

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

This might be question asked previously buti have tried every single solution possible for it. I have installed wamp server and the localhost is working fine. But when I load the PhpMyAdmin page then it will display a blank page. Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you see any error in your browser console or web server logs?

Comment: The web browser console is not showing any error when i will load phpmyadmi page then it will give me just a blank screen.